# Creating a percentage geom bar in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot

Im trying to get a figure of different variables (strategy) in to age groups (young vs old) in two gender group (female and male).
I have a data of these variables.
I uploaded them in R, and created a dataframe for them following this format:

```
crosstab <- xtabs(~strategy+age+gender, data = data2)
crosstab

tabframe <- as.data.frame(crosstab)
tabframe
```

so i have 20 observations in 4 variables (strategy, age, gender, Frequency).

Now when I plot it following the below code, I got a figure for 4% not 100%! and y is showing up with (counts) not (percentage) as Im expecting it.

```
rf <- ggplot(data = data2) +
  geom_bar(
    mapping = aes(x = age,
                  fill =strategy,
    ),
    position = position_dodge2(width = 0.9, preserve = "single"),
    colour="black"
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())+
  facet_grid(~gender, labeller = labeller(gender = saud_gender_names, task = saud_task_names)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=cbPalette)+
  scale_colour_manual(values=cbPalette)+
  theme_bw() + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("younger", "older")) +
  ggtitle("contour choice in ynqs")

rf
```

This is the photo I got

[image: plot1]

Can you help me solving this problem?

Best

I have tried to change many dataframe but it doesn't work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(data2)`, if that is not too large.

Comment: Hi, it is really too large to share it as dput(data2). I can explain further if there is a need

Comment: You can always supply a smaller, representative dataset. It really is difficult to help if we cannot reproduce the issue using some data. Linking to e.g. a shared Google sheet is another option.

Comment: dput(tabframe[1:4, ])
structure(list(strategy = structure(1:4, .Label = c("fall", "fall-rise", 
"level", "rise", "rise-fall"), class = "factor"), age = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("o", "y"), class = "factor"), gender = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("f", "m"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(9L, 
0L, 3L, 14L)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
>

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to re-create the issue you're seeing by running your code using the [reprex addin in RStudio](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/reprex-dos-and-donts.html). Producing a reprex that accurately reproduces an issue is key to finding and fixing the problem.

When I run the code you posted, I get various errors, e.g. because the code you've posted does not create the `cbPallete` object. Once I fixed those issues and removed lines of code that weren't relevant to the issue (e.g. lines that set the title, etc.), the following reprex was as close as I can get to the chart you posted the image of.

The reason why all the bars show 100% on the y axis is that there is only one observation in each combination of `strategy`, `age` and `gender`. Since `geom_bar()` counts observations, only one row having each unique combination of variables means `geom_bar()` produces a count of 1 and `percent_format()` renders that as 100%.

I can't tell if this problem happens because you've only provided a small number of rows of data in your post, or whether it's an issue with either (a) the actual data you're using or (b) the combination of variables you've chosen to `aggregate()`. Either way, it seems the problem is in the data rather than in your code -- the chart is rendering the data exactly as you've specified.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

data2 <- structure(
  list(
    strategy = structure(1:4, .Label = c("fall", "fall-rise", "level", "rise", "rise-fall"), class = "factor"), 
    age = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("o", "y"), class = "factor"), 
    gender = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("f", "m"), class = "factor"), 
    Freq = c(9L, 0L, 3L, 14L)
  ), 
  row.names = c(NA, 4L), 
  class = "data.frame"
)

tabframe <- as.data.frame(xtabs(~strategy+age+gender, data = data2))

# `tabframe` contains only a single row with each combination of variables
dplyr::count(tabframe, strategy, age, gender)

ggplot(data = tabframe) +
  geom_bar(
    mapping = aes(x = age, fill = strategy),
    position = position_dodge2(width = 0.9, preserve = "single")
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format()) +
  facet_grid(cols = vars(gender))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

If you still need help, it would probably be useful to post a larger sample of your data (maybe 20 rows?) using the [`dpasta()` function from the `datapasta` package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/datapasta-reprex.html#scenario-2-from-r-object-to-tibble-with-dpasta), since that would allow us to rule out any problems with your data more easily.

Comment: Thank you Matt, The same issue is here, the plot doesn't show variation, it shows 100% for all strategies! It also show 'count' in y, not precentage

Comment: @jojo I've updated my answer with some more information based on your comment. If that doesn't help, please post more of your data so I can check if that's what's causing the problem.